# Initializing object properties - how to do it properly

Tags: php, class, constructor, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Initializing Class Fields at the Field Definition or in Class Contructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157201/initializing-class-fields-at-the-field-definition-or-in-class-contructor)
>   [Setting variables on Constructor VS on the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484265/setting-variables-on-constructor-vs-on-the-class-definition)

What is the difference (if any) between the following 2 examples, and what is the proper way to initialize object properties?
Please note that the content of $fields in this case is something predefined, it will not change in runtime.

Example 1:

```
class User
{
    $fields = array('username', 'password', 'email');

    function __construct()
    {
    }    
}
```

Example 2:

```
class User {
    $fields;

     function __construct()
     {
         $this->fields = array('username', 'password', 'email');
     }     
}
```

Comment: @Brad Yes of course, this was just an example ;)

Comment: They have already default value... no need to Init them AGAIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example...  It is more explicit and obvious to the reader what the intention of `$fields` is...  "**something predefined**"